# Rotation of image with gl-react-image

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Why a rotation is applied to my picture?

bellow the dimensions:

```
               Object {
13:06:33 [exp]   "height": 3264,
13:06:33 [exp]   "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8196F3EA-3555-476F-B70F-E76CBBFBB3F8/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540devlyl%252Flyl/Camera/5FA1D6E2-D99E-4675-AF6E-CB96A2367015.jpg",
13:06:33 [exp]   "width": 1836,
13:06:33 [exp] }
```

Result of taken picture by the camera: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CESD.jpg

Displayed with GLImage:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Nl6.jpg

Related github issue: https://github.com/gre/gl-react-image/issues/22

**EDIT1:**

I found the related tutorial to make intagram filters using **react-native-gl** :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMAJLgafs6U

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution?

Comment: Are you using react-native-camera? And android or iOS?

Comment: In my project, it happens on IOS, haven't tested Android. It doesn't matter where the photo comes from. I guess it has something to do with the measurements.

Comment: I got this issue on android also, and it seem like a react-native bug https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1807. I work around by checking height, width and rotate the image by coding

Comment: Do you have a reprex (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @MaartenPeels maybe this answer can help you : https://github.com/gre/gl-react-image/issues/22#issuecomment-472145433

Comment: @Leonardo Alves Machado it's an old topic I haven't access to the code anymore.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado I have found the source code : https://medium.com/@wcandillon/instagram-filter-63e169a54ce3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a possible solution as mentioned in: **[github.com/gre/gl-react-image/issues/22](https://github.com/gre/gl-react-image/issues/22#issuecomment-472145433)**

> I had an issue similar to this and I fixed it by resizing the image before passing it as a uniform. Although I was using just the standard Node from "gl-react" not "gl-react-image".
> 3264 x 1836 is pretty big so I assume this is your issue also. Try halving this.
> Can be done on expo with https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/

For non Expo users the image can be resized with: **[bamlab/react-native-image-resizer](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer)**